# Continuously capturing a region of the screen

Tags: c#, bitmap, screen-capture

I am looking to continuously capture a region of the screen.

I am able to do this using `LockBits`, `BitBlt`, etc, but all my measurements have shown that it takes on average, 30 milliseconds to capture a single frame. It seems awfully similar to VSynch... which will try to keep the screen update rate at a constant 30ms...

However, I have just come across the [following post](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/b5e1ff6a-9e7d-4de9-8024-e1ddfad2b176/c-continuous-capturing-of-an-area-on-screen?forum=csharpgeneral).

In it, someone claims to get **1000 frames in 95 milliseconds**... that is unheard of (for me!). This is the code he has posted:

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using System.Diagnostics;
namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
  public partial class Form1 : Form
  {
    public Form1()
    {
      InitializeComponent();
    }
    private readonly Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
    private static Bitmap CaptureImage(int x, int y)
    {
      Bitmap b = new Bitmap(100, 100);
      using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(b))
      {
        g.CopyFromScreen(x, y, 0, 0, new Size(100, 100), CopyPixelOperation.SourceCopy);
        g.DrawLine(Pens.Black, new Point(0, 27), new Point(99, 27));
        g.DrawLine(Pens.Black, new Point(0, 73), new Point(99, 73));
        g.DrawLine(Pens.Black, new Point(52, 0), new Point(52, 99));
        g.DrawLine(Pens.Black, new Point(14, 0), new Point(14, 99));
        g.DrawLine(Pens.Black, new Point(85, 0), new Point(85, 99));
      }
      return b;
    }
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      Bitmap bmp = null;
      sw.Restart();
      for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
      {
         bmp = CaptureImage(390, 420);
      }
      sw.Stop();
      Console.WriteLine(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
    }
  }
}
```

I've tried it, and guess what.... I get ~30k milliseconds printed to console. So clearly this exact same code is still only capturing at 30ms/frame on my system. In his post, he says:

> there must be something drastically wrong with your system if the same
>   program takes 35 milliseconds to capture 1 frame.

This made me wonder, so I updated my graphics card drivers. Same result. Then I thought that perhaps my graphics card is old... OK, it is: AMD Radeon HD 5700 Series. Since I was suspecting VSync, I installed `AMD Catalyst Software Suite`, disabled Vsyc and restarted. Ran the test again and I got the same result: ~30k milliseconds for 1000 frames.

I then loaded up my `Amazon EC2 g2.2xlarge instance` with Windows 10 and NVIDIA GRID K520 drivers (up to date) installed. Same result: 30ms per frame.

Can someone with a bit more experience explain to me what is going on here?

Is it just not possible to do what the author claims and capture 1000 frames in 95ms?

Is there something wrong with my system? I don't know what else to try.

Comment: This depends on your graphics card. 30ms/frame is about 33 frames per second, it's about average and makes for decent motion picture. You can go higher but 10,000 frames per second is ridiculous. The monitor itself has a frequency of 70 hertz, so its useless to go above 70 frames per second. Although some fancy monitors can go up to 300 hertz. Also you are only copying 100x100 pixels, so your code will be even slower if you copy the whole screen.

Comment: @BarmakShemirani If this depends on the graphics card, why do I get ~30FPS on an Amazon EC2 G2.x2large instance? Also, how can I go higher?

Answer (score 0):

It is basically impossible to achieve 100,000 fps with current technology. The link to social.msdn.microsoft.com includes claims about achieving such results, but they are wrong or possibly confused between copying from memory to memory, versus copy from screen to memory.

The example below uses core WinAPI functions. On my computer (with cheap onboard graphic card) it achieves only 60 frames per second for a small area with 100 x 100 pixels. This will be slightly faster than the code in question, but you can probably achieve the same result with .net if you clean up your code.

Never the less, it only results in a small increase, 60 FPS or maybe 100 FPS for your computer (or less if you try to copy the whole screen)

Note that copying from memory to memory is much faster. I do get over 100,000 FPS, but it's not an actual frame on the screen. It's just copying from memory to memory. This speed will decrease if you increase the area to something bigger than 100x100 pixels.

Testing with cloud computers is not reliable. I am not even sure what it means to copy the screen on a cloud computer. Try testing on a desktop with better graphics card.

```
class Program
{
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern IntPtr GetDC(IntPtr ptr);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern bool ReleaseDC(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr hDC);

    [DllImport("Gdi32.dll")]
    static extern IntPtr CreateCompatibleDC(IntPtr hDC);

    [DllImport("Gdi32.dll")]
    static extern IntPtr CreateCompatibleBitmap(IntPtr hDC, int w, int h);

    [DllImport("Gdi32.dll")]
    static extern IntPtr BitBlt(IntPtr hDC, int x, int y, int w, int h, IntPtr hSrc, int sx, int sy, int mode);

    [DllImport("Gdi32.dll")]
    static extern IntPtr SelectObject(IntPtr hdc, IntPtr obj);

    [DllImport("Gdi32.dll")]
    static extern int DeleteObject(IntPtr hdc);

    [DllImport("Gdi32.dll")]
    static extern int DeleteDC(IntPtr hdc);

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        const int SRCCOPY = 0x00CC0020;
        int w = 100;
        int h = 100;

        //get screen dc:
        IntPtr hdc = GetDC((IntPtr)0);

        //create memory dc and bitmap, select bitmap in to memory:
        IntPtr memdc = CreateCompatibleDC(hdc);
        IntPtr hbitmap = CreateCompatibleBitmap(hdc, w, h);
        IntPtr holdbmp = SelectObject(memdc, hbitmap);

        //create another memory dc and bitmap:
        IntPtr memdc2 = CreateCompatibleDC(hdc);
        IntPtr hbitmap2 = CreateCompatibleBitmap(hdc, w, h);
        IntPtr holdbmp2 = SelectObject(memdc2, hbitmap2);

        Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();

        //copy the screen for 1 second
        sw.Restart();
        int fps = 0; //frames per second

        for (fps = 0; sw.ElapsedMilliseconds < 1000; fps++)
            BitBlt(memdc, 0, 0, w, h, hdc, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);
        sw.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine($"screen capture, FPS: {fps}");

        //copy from memory to memory for 1 second
        sw.Restart();
        fps = 0;
        for (fps = 0; sw.ElapsedMilliseconds < 1000; fps++)
            BitBlt(memdc, 0, 0, w, h, memdc2, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);
        sw.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine($"memory to memory copy, FPS: {fps}");

        //cleanup:
        SelectObject(memdc, holdbmp);
        SelectObject(memdc2, holdbmp2);
        DeleteObject(hbitmap);
        DeleteObject(hbitmap2);
        DeleteDC(memdc);
        DeleteDC(memdc2);
        ReleaseDC((IntPtr)0, hdc);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks - that is what I thought. Regarding the memory-to-memory copy, will that memory contain actual screen updates? For example, if I move a window into the 100x100 area, will the memory contain that update? If so, is it possible to extract "frames" at say 1 per millisecond? I need to capture and determine the moment a change occurs.

Comment: No that's just an example copying from uninitialized RAM memory, that's why it can reach high speed. Copying from screen is slow.

Comment: Hmm, I'm confused then. First, how can you copy from `uninitialised` RAM? Also, if it doesn't contain image data, what does it contain and what use is it?

Comment: `Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap)` is example of memory bitmap, you can use `Graphics` methods to draw on bitmap, it does not require a physical screen.